# CSS issue with Jquery chosen

Tags: css, jquery-chosen

Am using `Jquery Chosen plugin` and having some css issue.

There is a data-placeholder text which says "Select some options" default by chosen

But when it is displayed the text is getting truncated. I have list box of 50%. but that text is occupying 20% and getting truncated but when i chose from list everyting looks fine.

Did any one faced this issue with chosen ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a `width: '95%'` property

`$('.chosen-select').chosen({width: '95%'});` you can use it to re-size the width of the select box.

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing the same issue. I found a workaround for it. Copy the following CSS code:

```
.chosen-container input.default{width:100% !important}
```

This worked for me.